# Using CylonJS on Intel Edison- with Maxbotix sensor- Error no pin specified. Cannot proceed

Tags: node.js, intel-edison

Using this exact code for my nodeJS file on my Intel Edison referenced  from
http://cylonjs.com/documentation/drivers/maxbotix/

The only difference is in the line ***edison: { adaptor: 'intel-iot' }***

```
var Cylon = require('cylon');
Cylon.robot({
  connections: {
    edison: { adaptor: 'intel-iot' }
  },

  devices: {
    maxbotix: { driver: 'maxbotix' }
  },

  work: function(my) {
    every((1).seconds(), function() {
      my.maxbotix.range(function(data) {
        console.log("range: " + data);
      });
    });
  }
}).start();
```

I've done a npm install so all my modules are installed and doublechecked my wiring to ensure my sensor is connected properly.

Whenever I run the app I get the error

```
Error: No pin specified for Maxbotix. Cannot proceed
```

Any *arduino*, *nodejs* or *cyclonjs* experts able to suggest what is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the analog pin the maxbotix is connected to in the device definition, like this:

```
var Cylon = require('cylon');

Cylon.robot({
 connections: {
  edison: { adaptor: 'intel-iot' }
 },

 // should be one of the analog pins from 0 to  5
 // if using the arduino shield.
 devices: {
  maxbotix: { driver: 'maxbotix', pin: '1' }
 },

 work: function(my) {
  every((1).seconds(), function() {
   my.maxbotix.range(function(data) {
    console.log("range: " + data);
   });
  });
 }
}).start();
```

Comment: thanks getting closer. I see Initializing connections. Initializing devices. Starting connections. Starting devices. Working...and then nothing. I should be seeing the console.log message...